# storages in OpenCV with Python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to find contours in an image and further process them e.g. drawing them on the image.
To do that I have two functions running in different threads:

```
storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
contour = cv.FindContours(inData.content, storage, cv.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

and

```
while contours:
        bound_rect = cv.BoundingRect(list(contours))
        contours = contours.h_next()

        pt1 = (bound_rect[0], bound_rect[1])
        pt2 = (bound_rect[0] + bound_rect[2], bound_rect[1] + bound_rect[3])
        cv.Rectangle(inImg.content, pt1, pt2, cv.CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1)
```

Each function runs in a loop processing one image after the other.
When a function is done it puts the image in a buffer from which the other function can get it.
This works except that in the result the contours are drawn in the image one or two images before their corresponding image.

I think this has something to do with the storage of OpenCV but I don't understand why the storage is needed and what it does

**EDIT** Here is some more code:
My program is meant to be a node based image analasys software.
This is how the node graph of my current code looks like:

```
                         |---------|    |--------|
|-----|    |-----|------>|Threshold|--->|Contours|--->|-------------|    |------|
|Input|--->|Split|       |---------|    |--------|    |Draw Contours|--->|Output|
|-----|    |-----|----------------------------------->|-------------|    |------|
```

---

This is the class from which all nodes derive:

```
from Buffer import Buffer
from threading import Thread
from Data import Data
class Node(Thread):

    def __init__(self, inputbuffers, outputbuffers):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.inputbuffers = inputbuffers
        self.outputbuffers = outputbuffers
    def getInputBuffer(self, index):
        return self.inputbuffers[index]
    def getOutputBuffer(self, index):
        return self.outputbuffers[index]

    def _getContents(self, bufferArray):
        out = []
        for bufferToGet in bufferArray:
            if bufferToGet and bufferToGet.data:
                out.append(bufferToGet.data)
        for bufferToGet in bufferArray:
            bufferToGet.data = None
        return out
    def _allInputsPresent(self):
        for bufferToChk in self.inputbuffers:
            if not bufferToChk.data:
                return False
        return True
    def _allOutputsEmpty(self):
        for bufferToChk in self.outputbuffers:
            if bufferToChk.data != None:
                return False
        return True


    def _applyOutputs(self, output):
        for i in range(len(output)):
            if self.outputbuffers[i]:
                    self.outputbuffers[i].setData(output[i])

    def run(self):
        #Thread loop <------------------------------------
        while True:
            while not self._allInputsPresent(): pass
            inputs = self._getContents(self.inputbuffers)
            output = [None]*len(self.outputbuffers)
            self.process(inputs, output)
            while not self._allOutputsEmpty(): pass
            self._applyOutputs(output)

    def process(self, inputs, outputs):
        '''
        inputs: array of Data objects
        outputs: array of Data objects
        '''
        pass
```

---

The nodes pass around these Data objects:

```
class Data(object):

    def __init__(self, content = None, time = None, error = None, number = -1):
        self.content = content #Here the actual data is stored. Mostly images
        self.time = time #Not used yet
        self.error = error #Not used yet
        self.number = number #Used to see if the correct data is put together
```

---

This are the nodes:

```
from Node import Node
from Data import Data
import copy
import cv

class TemplateNode(Node):

    def __init__(self, inputbuffers, outputbuffers):

        super(type(self), self).__init__(inputbuffers, outputbuffers)

    def process(self, inputs, outputs):
        inData = inputs[0]
        #Do something with the content e.g.
        #cv.Smooth(inData.content, inData.content, cv.CV_GAUSSIAN, 11, 11)
        outputs[0] = inData

class InputNode(Node):

    def __init__(self, inputbuffers, outputbuffers):
        super(InputNode, self).__init__(inputbuffers, outputbuffers)
        self.capture = cv.CaptureFromFile("video.avi")
        self.counter = 0

    def process(self, inputs, outputs):
        image = cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)
        if image:
            font = cv.InitFont(cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 1, 0, 3, 8)
            x = 30
            y = 50
            cv.PutText(image, str(self.counter), (x,y), font, 255)
            outputs[0] = Data(image,None,None,self.counter)
            self.counter = self.counter+1

class OutputNode(Node):

    def __init__(self, inputbuffers, outputbuffers, name):
        super(type(self), self).__init__(inputbuffers, outputbuffers)
        self.name = name

    def process(self, inputs, outputs):
        if type(inputs[0].content) == cv.iplimage:
            cv.ShowImage(self.name, inputs[0].content)
            cv.WaitKey()

class ThresholdNode(Node):

    def __init__(self, inputbuffers, outputbuffers):
        super(type(self), self).__init__(inputbuffers, outputbuffers)

    def process(self, inputs, outputs):
        inData = inputs[0]
        inimg = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(inData.content), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        cv.CvtColor(inData.content, inimg, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
        outImg = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(inimg), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        cv.Threshold(inimg, outImg, 70, 255, cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
        inData.content = outImg
        outputs[0] = inData

class SplitNode(Node):

    def __init__(self, inputbuffers, outputbuffers):
        super(type(self), self).__init__(inputbuffers, outputbuffers)

    def process(self, inputs, outputs):
        inData = inputs[0]
        if type(inData.content) == cv.iplimage:
            imagecpy = cv.CloneImage(inData.content)
            outputs[1] = Data(imagecpy, copy.copy(inData.time), copy.copy(inData.error), copy.copy(inData.number))
        else:
            outputs[1] = copy.deepcopy(inData)
        print

class ContoursNode(Node):

    def __init__(self, inputbuffers, outputbuffers):
        super(type(self), self).__init__(inputbuffers, outputbuffers)

    def process(self, inputs, outputs):
        inData = inputs[0]

        storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
        contours = cv.FindContours(inData.content, storage, cv.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contoursArr = []
        while contours:
            points = []
            for (x,y) in contours:
                points.append((x,y))
            contoursArr.append(points)
            contours = contours.h_next()

        outputs[0] = Data(contoursArr, inData.time, inData.error, inData.number)
        pass


class DrawContoursNode(Node):

    def __init__(self, inputbuffers, outputbuffers):
        super(type(self), self).__init__(inputbuffers, outputbuffers)

    def process(self, inputs, outputs):
        inImg = inputs[0]

        contours = inputs[1].content

        print "Image start"
        for cont in contours:
            for (x,y) in cont:
                cv.Circle(inImg.content, (x,y), 2, cv.CV_RGB(255, 0, 0))
        print "Image end"
        outputs[0] = inImg
```

---

This is the main function. Here all the nodes and buffers are created.

```
from NodeImpls import *
from Buffer import Buffer

buffer1 = Buffer()
buffer2 = Buffer()
buffer3 = Buffer()
buffer4 = Buffer()
buffer5 = Buffer()
buffer6 = Buffer()

innode = InputNode([], [buffer1])
split = SplitNode([buffer1], [buffer2, buffer3])
thresh = ThresholdNode([buffer3], [buffer4])
contours = ContoursNode([buffer4], [buffer5])
drawc = DrawContoursNode([buffer2, buffer5],[buffer6])
outnode = OutputNode([buffer6], [], "out1")

innode.start()
split.start()
thresh.start()
contours.start()
drawc.start()
outnode.start()


while True:
    pass
```

---

The buffer:

```
class Buffer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None

    def setData(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def getData(self):
        return self.data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think this has something to do with the storage of OpenCV but I don't understand why the storage is needed and what it does

Storage is just a place to keep the results. OpenCV is a C++ library, and relies on manual memory allocation, C++ style. Python bindings are just a thin wrapper around it, and are not very *pythonic*. That's why you have to allocate storage manually, like if you did it in C or in C++.

> I have two functions running in different threads
>   ...
>   This works except that in the result the contours are drawn in the image one or two images before their corresponding image.

I assume your threads are not properly synchronized. This problem is not likely to be related to OpenCV, but to what functions you have, what data they use and pass around, and how you share the data between them.

In short, please post your code where you create threads and call these functions, as well where `inImg`, `inData`, `contour`, `contours` and `storage` are accessed or modified.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I added my code to the question.

Comment: @AntonS In your source I see that different threads (Nodes) share the same data (buffers) without locks. The fastest thread goes ahead, and overwrites its output buffer with new data. To synchronize every producer-consumer pair, you can use condition objects http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#condition-objects Another link: http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm#synchronization-between-threads See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem Consider also using `deque` for queues http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Comment: @AntonS In fact I doubt threads give any advantage here. There is no parallelism or concurrency in the dataflow, and with proper synchronization all threads will wait for the slowest one (DrawContours?). Practically that means they'll work sequentially as in normal sequential code, but with much more effort to organize correct syncrhonization. Implement nodes as usual functions, and infinitely loop through them. Synchronization problem solved, your code is faster (less overhead) and more maintanable.

Comment: Concerning your 2. point:
I think there is parallelism in my program. Its right that there are no parallel branches, but e.g. the Threshold node can process image 10 while the Contours node is processing image 9.

Comment: Concerning your 1. point:
I used 'Queues' instead of buffers. But that made no difference.
I don't understand why I have to synchronise the threads: Because of the queues two threads should never try to use the same image.

Comment: I made the node setup simpler to test it. Now it looks like this:
`Input-Threshold-Output`. Also I directly stored the images in the queues without the data objects around them. But that also changed nothing.
The images often come like this: 0,2,4,4,6,7,7,8,9,10,12... So some imaged are doubled and some are lost.
I uploaded the simpler version of my code here: [link](http://www.2shared.com/file/Efk8OY2P/ImageProcessing.html)

Comment: If threads access common data, they _have_ to synchronize. Otherwise you have race condition and the result is unpredictable. Queues go afterwards as an improvement.

Comment: On parallelism: Threshold can start processing image 10, but it cannot write its results to output buffer until it _knows_ that Countours is free and ready to accept it. In short, threads have to wait for each-other. A propos: there is a synchronized Queue class http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html It should take care of synchronization.

Comment: I now replaced opencv with mahotas and used the Queue class, and it worked. Thanks for your help!